# How to print line numbers for a multi-line character variable in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify line numbers in a JAGS script stored in a scalar character variable.
I want to add line numbers to `cat` output in R.

To simplify the example, if I had a string:

```
x <- "A\nB\nC"
```

and I do `cat(x)`, I get:

```
A
B
C
```

How can I print line numbers with the string. I.e., to display something like:

```
1: A
2: B
3: C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this without manually adding those line numbers in yourself.  It's not too bad to do though.

```
line_num_cat <- function(x){
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))
  cat(paste0(seq_len(length(tmp)), ": ", tmp, collapse = "\n"), "\n")
}

x <- "A\nB\nC"
line_num_cat(x)
```

which gives

```
> line_num_cat(x)
1: A
2: B
3: C
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
x <- "A\nB\nC"

list_x <- strsplit(x,"\n")

cat(paste0(1:length(list_x[[1]]), ": ", list_x[[1]]), sep="\n")
```

the result:

```
1: A
2: B
3: C
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).